# Media query not responsive. The color is not changing and the menu is not collapsing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

/*     Viewport less than or equal to 750px     */

```
@media only screen and(max-width:750px){
    .nav{
    background: black;
        }
}
```

/*    x   Viewport less than or equal to 750px x     */

Comment: please, be more specific

Comment: We can't really tell what might be gong wrong, with so little information. Please get into the habit of presenting proper [mre]s of such issues, when asking here.

Comment: Is nav a class or a tag?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the only and add a space between the `and` and the brackets so css can read the styling properly. This is what it should look like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .nav{
    background: black;
        }
}
```

In the future, try asking more specific questions as well and adding all relevant code to the question.